# TesseractOCR custom training

Tags: tesseract-ocr

I don't get it how am I supposed to tell Tesseract that this is actually `a b c` letters?

Appending makebox in cli, produced this file:

```
C 78 127 104 166 0
l 96 127 118 166 0
. 116 127 126 140 0
- 124 127 130 145 0
j 145 127 162 188 0
o 154 127 183 158 0
b 203 131 241 164 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [link](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) to know more about how to train tesseract.
To correct the box files you can use [jTessBoxEditor](http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html). 
Do keep in mind at times you might need to preprocess the images.